# Non-measurable group homomorphisms from $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ to itself.

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

It is a well-known theorem of Pettis (see, for instance, the following expository note of Andrew Putman [https://www3.nd.edu/~andyp/notes/AutomaticContinuity.pdf](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Eandyp/notes/AutomaticContinuity.pdf)) that any measurable homomorphism between Lie groups is automatically continuous (and hence, also smooth).

I would like to see some explicit constructions of non-measurable homomorphisms of, say, matrix Lie groups. For instance, how does one construct a non-measurable homomorphism $\phi : \mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{C}) \rightarrow \mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{C})$? I have heard that this can be done by applying some field automorphism (other than complex conjugation) to each of the entries, but I do not understand why this makes the homomorphism non-measurable (it is sufficient, by the above theorem of Pettis, to show that the homomorphism is not continuous).

Any details or references would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you could construct such homomorphisms for the Lie group $\mathbb{C}$ itself first? I guess for that, something like "Take elements $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ from $\mathbb{C}$ such that $\mathbb{C}$ is generated freely (in some precise sense) over $\mathbb{Q}$ by these $x_i$ as an algebra. Now permute these $x_i$." will work. It is easy to make these maps non-continuous, but non-Lebesgue-measurable might be more difficult. What measure do you have?

Comment: @student91 The most natural measure would just be the Haar measure.

Comment: There are only two continuous field automorphisms of $\Bbb{C}$, but $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ permutations of any base of transcendance over $\Bbb{Q}$, each one inducing a field automorphism of $\Bbb{C}$.

If $f$ is such a discontinuous $\Bbb{C}$-automorphism, then $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\ c&d\end{smallmatrix}\right)
\mapsto\left(\begin{smallmatrix}f(a)&f(b)\\ f(c)&f(d)\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ is a discontinuous automorphism of $\mathop{\rm SL}(2,\Bbb{C})$.

(But this is not an “explicit” construction, depending on how one defines _explicit_…)

Comment: @jpboucheron thank you! That makes a lot of sense!

Comment: @AleksanderSkenderi You're welcome.